# How to Populate WPF Datagrid by using WCF Service

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I want to call `WCF Service` for binding a datagrid Control in `WPF`, and perform insert,update and delete in `WPF datagrid` . Can anyone give me a sample project with clear explanations on WCF Service and how to add it as a service reference to WPF datagrid and perform various operations?

Comment: WCF Data Services or WCF?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code I hope you will find useful:

```
namespace SilverlightApplication1
{
  public partial class MainPage : UserControl
  {
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        FillDataGrid();
    }

    private void FillDataGrid()
    {
        Service1Client client = new Service1Client();
        client.GetAllEmpCompleted += new
            EventHandler<GetAllEmpCompletedEventArgs>(client_GetAllEmpCompleted);
        client.GetAllEmpAsync();
    }

    void client_GetAllEmpCompleted(object sender, GetAllEmpCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        GridTest.ItemsSource = e.Result;

    }
  }
}
```

Source: https://chandradev819.wordpress.com/2010/09/21/easiest-way-to-consume-wcf-service-and-fill-datagrid-from-database-in-silverlight/